# How to select specific lines with input function

Tags: pandas, select, input, line

I am Federico
I am working on Pandas to process an excel file with 66 lines, and three columns that contain strings

My idea would be using the input function provided in Pandas to choose only the lines that correspond to a specific name in the first column, but the software continues to give me error (truth value is ambiguous)
Could anyone explain me what is the right code to write?
Thank you

Federico

I tried to select some lines that contains in the column ‘City’ the name of that city, chosen with input, but continues to give me error

Comment: can you try:  newdf= df.loc[df['City'].str.contains("london", na=False)]